# Python: sorting string numbers not lexicographically

Tags: python

I have an array of string-numbers, like:

```
numbers = ['10', '8', '918', '101010']
```

When I use `sorted(numbers)`, I get them sorted lexicographically, e.g. `'8' > '17'`.

How can I iterate over the strings sorted according to the number value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the built-in `sorted()` function with a key `int` to map each item in your list to an integer prior to comparison:

```
numbers = ['10', '8', '918', '101010']
numbers = sorted(numbers, key=int)
print(numbers)
```

**Output**

```
['8', '10', '918', '101010']
```

Using this method will output a list of strings as desired.

Comment: looks like a great and a very elegant solution

Answer (score 3):

You can transform the elements of the array to integers by using the built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function.

```
print sorted(map(int, numbers))
```

Output:

```
[8, 10, 918, 101010]
```

Comment: Nice, and then I can use `str()` in order to get a string again. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep as strings  you can pass `int` as the key to `list.sort` which will sort the original list:

```
numbers = ['10', '8', '918', '101010']
numbers.sort(key=int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I like to do it, which is very fast.

```
print(sorted(sorted(numbers), key=len))
```

Comment: It would be good to explain why you need to use sorted() twice.

Answer (score 0):

all elements types are string,

```
 >>> x=['4', '5', '29', '54', '4', '0', '-214', '542', '-64', '1', '-3', '6', '-6']
 >>> max(x)
 '6'
```

It "orders" the words alphabetically and returns the one that is at the bottom of the alphabetic list

Few more examples:

```
    >>> list1 = ['kyle', 'dhamu']
    >>> max(list1)
    'kyle'
```

returns kyle because k is after d

Also remember from python3.7 you cannot mix strings and integers to use max function. Below is the example

```
>>> mix_list = ['my', 'name', 'is', 1 ]
>>> max(mix_list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```